# How can I only show 2 specific files and all folders inside public_html with FileZilla?

Tags: filezilla, file-filter

I'm trying to use the FileZilla filters to only show my index.php, config.php files and all folders that reside in the public_html folder. My tree is something like below. I only want to show the bold files.

/public_html/

- **folder1/**

  - **index.php**
  - **config.php**
  - otherfiles.ext
- **folder2/**

  - images/

    - image.png
  - **index.php**
  - **config.php**
  - other.php
- **otherfolder/**

  - otherfiles.ext
- otherfiles.ext
- **index.php**

I can only manage to show the index.php and config.php files by using:

- filename = index.php
- filename = config.php

For showing the folders I've tried some regexes on filesnames and paths and filesize < 0. Nothing works for me.

Can anyone tell me how I can show the combination of these files and folders through the FileZilla file filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's *"Filter applies to"* checkbox group on the bottom of the filter dialog.

Just uncheck the *"Directories"* checkbox there.